# Function $\phi: V \to V^\ast$ is a linear isomorphism where $\phi (v) = v^\ast$ and $v^\ast$ is a Kronecker delta on the basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v \in V$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $\beta$ basis of $V$ containing $v$. Then define for every $v \in V$ an element $v^\ast \in V ^\ast$ defined in the basis $\beta$ as $v^\ast(v)= 1$ and $v^\ast(u)=0$ for every $u \in \beta / \lbrace v \rbrace$. Then we define a morphism $\phi: V \to V^\ast$ as $\phi (v) = v^\ast$. I want to prove that $\phi$ as defined above is a linear isomorphism. But the problems begin proving $\phi$ is indeed linear. Proving $\phi ( \lambda v) = \lambda \phi (v)$ for every $\lambda \in F$ and $v \in V$ is easy but proving $\phi (v+w) = \phi (v) + \phi (w)$ is not clear to me. I mean the last is equivalent to proving $(v+w)^\ast =v ^\ast + w ^ \ast$ but this is not easy to see (at least for me) since for $v^\ast$ we need an specific basis containing $v$, the same case with $w^\ast$ and for $(v+w)^\ast$. So for proving $(v+w)^\ast =v ^\ast + w ^ \ast$ we need to show the assignations are equal (at least in a basis). But this is not clear :(. There are other proofs showing $V$ and $V^\ast$ are isomorphic so it suffices to prove $\phi$ is injective or surjective.

Comment: Your definition of $\phi$ doesn't really make sense. You can't define this for any $v\in V$, not every element belongs to your chosen basis. You can define it like this only on vectors in the basis $\beta$, and this map has a unique extension to a linear map $V\to V^*$.

Comment: Is there any way to correct this assignation of $phi$? Or how can I extend it to a morphism  from $V$ \to $V^\ast$ ?

Comment: If $B$ is a basis of $V$, and $W$ is some vector space, then any function $f:B\to W$ can be uniquely extended to a linear map $V\to W$ in a very natural way. (every element in $V$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of elements of $B$, so it's clear how this linear map has to be defined) So define $\phi$ on the elements of $\beta$ as you did, and extend this function to a linear map $V\to V^*$. Then you have to show it is an isomorphism.

Comment: So by this universal construction this extension is linear right? In theory I undestand is right  but still byexpressing $v,w \in V$ it is nor clear why the extension let´s say $\bar(\phi)$ satisfies $\bar{\phi}(v+w) = \bar{\phi}(v)+ \bar {\phi(w)}$? Also is this extension an isomorphism from $V \to V^\ast$? @Mark

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your definition is that you try to define $v^\ast$ manually for each $v \in V$ in a way, which is not linear. Let me explain, how to define $\phi$ properly, then you will see, why your definition is flawed.

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $B \subseteq V$ and $W$ another vector space. Recall the extension theorem, which tells you that if you provide a function $\phi_B:B \rightarrow W$, this uniquely extends to a *linear* map $\phi:V \rightarrow W$. This holds, because linearity forces you to send a linear combination $\sum_i \lambda_i b_i$ to a linear combination $\sum_i \lambda_i \phi_B(b_i)$ and every vector $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as such a linear combination.

We can use this to show that for any given basis vector $b\in B$ there is function
$$b^\ast_B:B\rightarrow K, c\mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&c=b\\
0&\text{else}\end{array}\right.$$
which induces a unique linear map $$b^\ast:V\rightarrow K, \sum_i \lambda_i b_i \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\lambda_j &\text{if }\exists j: b_j = b\\0&\text{else}\end{array}\right.$$

Putting all the linear maps $(b^\ast)_{b\in B}$ together we obtain a function
$$\phi_B:B\rightarrow V^\ast, b \mapsto b^\ast$$
and by applying the extension theorem again, we get a linear map
$$\phi:V\rightarrow V^\ast, \sum_i \lambda_i b_i \mapsto \sum_i \lambda_i b_i^\ast$$

Note that linearity comes for free, since we used the extension theorem. Note also that as soon as we require that $\phi(b) = b^\ast$ for all $b\in B$ we have no other choice for $\phi$, since the extension theorem provides a *unique* extension.

Now let us fix two basis vectors $b$ and $c$ and try to figure out what happens with a nontrivial linear combination of both, say $v=b+c$. By the explicit formula above we find that $\phi(v) = b^\ast + c^\ast:V\rightarrow K$. Let us evaluate this function at $v$. We get
$$\begin{align*}
\phi(v)(v) &= (b^\ast + c^\ast)(v) \\&= b^\ast(v) + c^\ast(v)\\&= b^\ast(b+c) + c^\ast(b+c) \\&= 1+1 = 2\end{align*}$$
and **not** $\phi(v)(v) = 1$, as you wished.